# how to overwrite a specific segment of a line within a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have this function which I want to scan through an entire text file line by line (the text files lines have splits in them with ',' so that it can be used for different segments so that I can class my data more simply. however I do not know how to overwrite a specific segment within a line, so lets say that every line is split up with 4 segments and it looks like this:

*Athena,£2,233.33,Y*

(I have already done the calculations for all of my lines so this isnt an issue for me)

I essentially want to be able to say:

```
If segment 4 isnt equal to N:
   volunteer_file.line(i).segment4.write ("N")
```

I know that the code above isn't accurate to the actual code that would be used but since I don't know it i just want to put that there so that you understand where I'm heading from.

I simply want to overwrite a certain portion of a line of code in the txt file itself

Comment: There's no way to overwrite a line in the middle of a file. You need to read the file into memory (probably a `str` or `list` of `str`), make your changes to the contents in memory, and then write the contents to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `fileinput`. fileinput supports inplace editing.

```
   import fileinput
    
    with fileinput.FileInput('sample.txt',inplace=True) as file_obj:
        for line in file_obj:
            x = line.split(',')
            for i,word in enumerate(x):
                if i == 3 and word == 'Y':
                    print(line.replace('Y', 'N'), end='')
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however I am displeased to say that I have no idea how to actually implement this within the code that I have made, so far I have attempted to implement this but it is not working as it just removes all of the contents within my txt file and I dont know how to change this.